# Django : Heroku App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt

Tags: django, heroku, robots.txt

[My app works fine on localhost but whenever i push it to heroku it gives the error below and app crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFodw.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to explain your problem if you want to be answered. What does your app ? Did you try to understand the issue before coming here ? What did you find and where exactly are you stuck ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app needs support for the path. Please read more about `robots. txt`, or search for django solution. Here is [blog post](http://fredericiana.com/2010/06/09/three-ways-to-add-a-robots-txt-to-your-django-project/) with sample solutions.

## Edit

I think Heroku uses `robots` for some internal purposes. That is why you get the error.

As a side note - please put logs as text, inside the post. That way all can be sure that it will not disappear in the future.

Comment: click on the question and you will be able to see the logs

Comment: I know that, but it is much better to copy-paste from text then retype from picture. Also after some time you can decide to remove it, while having it here - guarantee question consistency... That is why people insists on that. At least - note for the future.